# Release process of buildfarm

Tags: ros, buildfarm, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

currently I have a failing build (xenial, x64) in Travis due to a missing package on the shadow-fixed repository.

The package is "ros-kinetic-moveit-planners-ompl", yet I don't want to solve this special issue, but gain more understanding of the overall process.

In the build farm I see that everythink works:
http://build.ros.org/view/Kbin_uX64/job/Kbin_uX64__moveit_planners_ompl__ubuntu_xenial_amd64__binary/

On the status page of repositories.ros.org I can see that there is currently no green light on (testing aka shadow-fixed)
[image: image description]

Also on http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-kinetic-moveit-planners-ompl/
there is no debian package for the respective architecture.

[image: image description]

How could I gain more insight what is happening here and why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298368/release-process-of-buildfarm/) by [agutenkunst](https://answers.ros.org/users/30729/agutenkunst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2018-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When a new package is built and added to the buildfarm repository, packages which depend on it are removed from the repo before being rebuilt with the newly built dependency in order to prevent syncing packages with an inconsistent and possibly incompatible state to the testing and eventually main repositories.

Syncs to the testing repo wait for the last in-progress build to finish before running automatically. If a package fails and doesn't get rescheduled before a sync runs and there are enough packages built successfully, the sync will occur and remove those packages from the testing repository. Later, when the build is retriggered, the missing packages should sync once all packages in the distro finish.

The buildfarm is designed to be somewhat [eventually consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) with failures do to operational glitches being resolved automatically by later syncs.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1